# Pandas remove characters between brackets

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to remove characters between `[]` and currently I am doing

```
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]","")
```

But the output isn't desirable. Before it is `[image] This document` and after it is `******* This document` where `*` is whitespace.

How do I get rid of this white space.

**Edit 1**

The `Text` column of `df` looks like below:

```
ID    Text
0     REAL ESTATE LEASE THIS INDUSTRIAL REAL ESTAT...
5     Lease AureementMade and signed on the \ of Aug...
6     FIRST AMENDMENT OF LEASEDATE: August 31, 2001L...
8     [image: image0.jpg] Jack[image: image1.jb2] ...
9     [image: image0.jpg] ABC SALES Meeting 97...
14    FIRST AMENDMENT OF LEASETHIS FIRST AMENDMENT O...
17    [image: image0.tif] Deep ML LEASE SERVI...
22    [image: image0.jpg] F 15 083 EX [image: image1...
26    LEASE AGREEMENT—GROSS LEASEBASIC LEASE PROVISI...
28    [image: image0.jpg] 17. Medical VERIFICATION...
31    [image: image0.jpg]  [image: image1.jb2] PLL 3...
32    SUBLEASETHIS SUBLEASE this “Sublease” made as ...
34    [image: image0.tif] Lease Agreement May 10, 20...
35    13057968.3  1 Initials:  _____  _____  SECOND ...
42    [image: image0.jpg] Jack Dowson Buy Real MI...
46     Deep – Machine Learning LEASE   B...
```

I would like to see

```
ID    Text
0     REAL ESTATE LEASE THIS INDUSTRIAL REAL ESTAT...
5     Lease AureementMade and signed on the \ of Aug...
6     FIRST AMENDMENT OF LEASEDATE: August 31, 2001L...
8     Jack ...
9     ABC SALES Meeting 97...
14    FIRST AMENDMENT OF LEASETHIS FIRST AMENDMENT O...
17    Deep ML LEASE SERVI...
22    F 15 083 EX ...
26    LEASE AGREEMENT—GROSS LEASEBASIC LEASE PROVISI...
28    17. Medical VERIFICATION...
31    PLL 3...
32    SUBLEASETHIS SUBLEASE this “Sublease” made as ...
34    Lease Agreement May 10, 20...
35    13057968.3  1 Initials:  _____  _____  SECOND ...
42    Jack Dowson Buy Real MI...
46    Deep – Machine Learning LEASE   B...
```

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on how to ask a good question may also be useful.

Comment: `df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(r"\[.*\]","").str.strip()`?

Comment: If I use @Rakesh 's solution, it removes the entire row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you need `.str.strip()`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3], "Text": ["[image: 123.jpg] This document", "[image: image.jpg] Readers of the article", "The agreement between [image: image.jpg] two parties"]})
df["Text"] = df["Text"].str.replace(r"(\s*\[.*?\]\s*)", " ").str.strip()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0                        This document
1               Readers of the article
2    The agreement between two parties
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Note that there are **two** spaces between words *between* and *two*, so this proposition doesn't do the job. *str.strip()* removes leading and trailing spaces from the **whole** text, not before/after each match.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo. Thanks did not see that.

Answer (score 4):

Add optional space (`?`) to your regex, so the whole regex (match part) should be:

```
r'\[.*\] ?'
```

Another hint: Your regex is enclosed in parentheses (a capturing group).
They are not needed. Remove them.